# Show that $u(x)$ is a constant for almost all $x$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $u \in L^¹_{loc}(a,b)$ and $$\int_a^b u(x) \phi'(x) \ dx=0$$ for all $\phi \in C^{\infty}_{c}(a,b)$.

How can I show that there exists a real constant $c$ such that $u(x)=c$ for almost all $x \in [a,b] \ $?

If I chose a function $\phi$ such that $\phi(a)=\phi(b)=0$ I get $$0=\int_a^b u(x) \phi'(x) \ dx=-\int_a^b u'(x) \phi(x) \ dx$$ using partial integration, is that right? How can I now conclude there $u(x)=c$ ?
Some hints are much appreciated.

Comment: What you are trying to show is a sightly modified version of the fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations.  Hint:  Assume it is not the case, i.e., there exists a non constant function that satisfies the identity. Then you should be able to derive a contradiction.

Comment: @almosteverywhere oh ok, so I can just conclude that $u'=0$ using that Lemma and therefore $u(x)=c$

Comment: The second equation you have makes sense only if $u$ has a weak derivative. Since you have just assumed $u \in L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$ this is not necesssarily true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any $\psi \in C_c^\infty(a,b)$ havng mean zero can be written as $\phi'$
for some $\phi \in C_c^\infty(a,b)$. Thus $u$ satisfies the equation
\begin{align}
\int_a^b u \psi \, {\rm d}x =0 , \quad \forall \psi \in C_c^\infty(a,b), \int_a^b \psi \, {\rm d}x=0 \,.
\end{align} 
Also by a density argument (test functions are weak-$\star$ dense in $L^\infty$) the above statment must also hold true for any $\psi \in L^\infty(a,b)$ having mean zero.
Assume $u$ is not constant a.e., then the set $A:=\{x \in(a,b): u(x) > (b-a)^{-1}\int u\}$ has positive (but not full ) measure (if not then it must hold for $A:=\{x \in(a,b): u(x) < (b-a)^{-1} \int u\}$ and then you can continue with the same arguments). Now let $f= |A|^{-1}\chi_A - |A^c|^{-1}\chi_{A^c}
\in L^\infty$, mean zero. Then
\begin{align}
\int_a^b u f \, {\rm d}x >  (b-a)^{-1}\int u - (b-a)^{-1}\int u >0
\end{align}
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. But I am wondering:

There is then at least a weak derivative of $u$, let's call it $g \in L^1_{loc}$. Thus putting $g$ instead of $u'$ into the right integral of my second equation we can follow  $g = 0$ using the fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations. That means that $ u= c$ almost everywhere since its weak derivative vanishes.
Or where am I wrong?

Comment: If you assume that $u$ has a weak derivative then you can apply to fundamental lemma to argue that $g=0$ a.e. However to show that this implies that $u$ is constant a.e. is the same as your original question, if you see what I mean. The argument becomes circular

Comment: Oh sorry, you said there is not necessarily a weak derivative. I misread it on Wikipedia. It said there might exist a weak derivative, not it does.

Comment: Okay thanks, I fully got your proof now. So which additional conditions must be given so that I know that there is a weak derivative for sure?

Comment: Ah okay, so conditions on $u$ must be given but which was not the case here. Properties had to be proven. Got a little confused. Thanks for all!

Comment: Usually one would specify explicitly that $u$ is weakly differentiable, something like $u \in W^{1,1}_{\rm loc}$ would work. Other conditions you could specify are absolute continuity or Lipschitz continuity both of which would give you differentiability a.e. and thus weak differentiability